# Clone <div> in jQuery using clone() function

Tags: jquery

I want to clone my `<div>` and apprend it just before the Add link.

## Actual code

```
<div class="form-group">Text</div>
<i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add
```

## I try:

```
$(function(){
  var $button = $('.fa-plus').clone();
  $('.form-group').html($button);
});
```

It did not work.

Could you please help ?

Thanks.

Comment: Also, according to your question, you want to clone the div?  That should be $('.form-group').clone() ???

Answer (score 0):

basic googling skills, first result, [jQuery .clone()](http://api.jquery.com/clone/)

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>clone demo</title>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<b>Hello</b><p>, how are you?</p>

<script>
$( "b" ).clone().prependTo( "p" );
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: - On the first click, it clones my 1st row : perfect.
 - On the second click, it clones 2 rows : not perfect.

Comment: of course because my example targets all `<b>` tags. on 2nd click you have 2 of those because you ave cloned it once already therefore all of them are being coppied. you need to target a specific element each time, thats all. my point was to use the `.prependTo` instead of `.html`

Answer (score 0):

Use `.after()` to put it after the DIV. `.html()` replaces the contents of the DIV.

```
$(function() {
    var button = $('.fa-plus').clone();
    $('.form-group').after(button);
});
```

Comment: - On the first click, it clones my 1st row : perfect.
 - On the second click, it clones 2 rows : not perfect.

Comment: You asked it to clone everything that matches the selector. If you want it to clone just one row, use a more specific selector, like `$('.fa-plus:first')`.